# Getting a Hermite polynomial expansion of Gaussian with given variance.

Tags: normal-distribution, orthogonal-polynomials

I am trying to find an expansion of centered Gaussian - $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp({-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})}$ in terms of Hermite polynomials.

Namely to calculate $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp({-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}})}H_{n}(x)\exp({-\frac{x^2}{2})}dx$

Any comments are welcome.

---

Edited later:

"""

Equivalently, I am looking for the value of -

$a_n=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp({-\frac{x^2}{\alpha}})}H_{n}(x)dx$

for some arbitrary $\alpha$

"""

Comment: The integrands of two parts of the question are not the same. In the first part, the integrand is: $exp(.)H[x] exp(.)$. In the second part, the integrand is $exp(.) H[x]$.

Comment: If you add exponents you get the general form as in the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hermite expansion of the probability distribution function for $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$
$$
 \omega_\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
is
$$
 \omega_\sigma(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!2^m \sqrt{2\pi\left(\sigma^2+1\right)^{2m+1}}}H_{2m}(x).
$$

The starting point is the expression for the general coefficient for any function $f(x)=\sum_n d_n H_n(x)$ is given by the expression
$$
 d_n = \frac{1}{n!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial^n f(x)}{\partial x^n} \omega(x) dx,
$$
which, by the definition of the stretched Hermite polynomials $ H_n\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) = \frac{(-\sigma)^n}{\omega_\sigma(x)}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\omega_\sigma(x)$,
reduces to
$$
  d_n = \frac{1}{(-\sigma)^nn!\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right) \omega_\sigma(x)\omega(x)dx.
$$
The product $\omega_\sigma(x)\omega(x)$ can be transformed into $\omega(y)$ by the change of variables $y = \frac{x}{\sigma}\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}$.

The integral of a general stretched Hermite polynomial
$$
 I_\alpha =\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_\alpha(\gamma x)\omega(x)dx
$$
can be done via a Taylor expansion
$$
 I_\alpha = \sum_{\beta=0}^{\alpha} {\alpha \choose\beta} H_{\alpha-\beta}(0)\gamma^\beta \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^\beta\omega(x)dx
$$
with result
$$
 I_{\alpha} = (\alpha-1)!!\left(\gamma^2-1\right)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}.  
$$
Putting this into the formula for $d_n$, we get
$$
  d_n = \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{(\sigma)^nn!\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma^2+1)}}(n-1)!!\left(\frac{-\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} & n\textrm{ even}\\
   0 & n \textrm{ odd},
   \end{cases}
$$
which, after a reindex of the summation leads to the expansion given at the start of this answer.

Please read my recently submitted manuscript https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352374514_A_GENERAL_EXPRESSION_FOR_HERMITE_EXPANSIONS_WITH_APPLICATIONS
for all of the details.

Answer (score 5):

If $\hat{H}_{n}$ are the normalized Hermite functions, and $-1 < r < 1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n}\hat{H}_{n}(x)^{2} & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(1-r^{2})}}\exp\left(-\frac{1-r}{1+r}x^{2}+x^{2}\right) \\
          & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(1-r^{2})}}\exp\left(\frac{2r}{1+r}x^{2}\right).
\end{align}
$$
The normalized $\hat{H}_{n}$ are chosen so that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{H}_{n}(x)e^{-x^{2}}dx = 1$. By choosing $r$ appropriately, you can get what you want. Look for Mehler's kernel on this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions . You'll find more information about how one derives the above special case of Mehler's kernel $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n}H_{n}(x)H_{n}(y)$ where $x=y$.

Comment: Could you kindly explain how does one prove that the Mehler kernel expansion converges?

Comment: @Anirbit : Proving the Mehler expansion is not particularly easy. The first version I found was in Norbert Wiener's book *The Fourier Integral and Certain of Its Applications* (Chapter 1, Section 7, "The Generating Function of the Hermite Functions"). I'm sure there must be other versions out there, and ones that are simpler.

Comment: Thanks! Let me look up that reference! This is particularly confusing because the upper bound on the Hermite polynomials is exponentially diverging and hence I have no intuition for its convergence!

Comment: And is this a pointwise convergence (uniform on compact sets?) or is this a convergence in the sense of L^2 norm (which is like a convergence on average) ?

Comment: @Anirbit : Uniform on compact subsets.

Comment: Wow! So this is much stronger than just L^2 convergence!? Its not just that the square of the difference between partial sums of the series and the kernel when integrated over all space tends to 0? Its like "for all" pairs of points this converges uniformly on compact sets?

Comment: @Anirbit Actually, the Mehler kernel expansion converges uniformly to the bivariate Gaussian for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. The convergence is uniform on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: WoW! So not just on compact sets but on the entire plane!?

Comment: @Anirbit : Yes, but before it sounds too good, keep this in mind: uniform convergence on the plane is not enough to give you $L^2$ convergence. So when you want to put this into an integral and interchange limits, you have to start with functions that are compactly supported or are in $L^1$. There's something odd going on with the tails it seems, and you might expect that because of the increasing degree of polynomials involved in the sum.